# Not able to access variable outside of second function in reactive programming

Tags: typescript, rxjs, nestjs

I have 2 Javascript functions. The first returns value to the second. In the second function, I am not able to access a constant declared earlier.

I have tried renaming the constant.

```
//app.service.ts

import { Injectable, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()

export class AppService implements OnModuleInit {

  constant1 = 'constant1';

  onModuleInit() {
    this.someFunction1()
    .pipe(
      this.someFunction2,
    ).subscribe(console.log);
  }

  private someFunction1(): Observable<string> {
    console.log('someFunction1');
    console.log('constant1 = ', this.constant1);
    return of('done');
  }

  private someFunction2(something:Observable<string>):Observable<string> {
    console.log('someFunction1');
    console.log('constant1 = ', this.constant1); 
    // Cannot read property of constant1
    return of('done');
  }

}
```

I expect the output is 'constant1'. But I get an error of 'cannot read property of constant1.'

Comment: Use `this.someFunction2.bind(this)`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/9423231

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `this` is not bound to the `AppService` because of its invocation:

```
onModuleInit() {
  this.someFunction1()
    // You are passing someFunction2 as a function expression
    .pipe(this.someFunction2)
    .subscribe(console.log);
}
```

Instead pass `someFunction2` as an arrow function where `this` is lexically bound, meaning that whatever `this` is for the caller of the arrow function it will be the same within the arrow function:

```
onModuleInit() {
  this.someFunction1()
    .pipe(something => this.someFunction2(something))
    .subscribe(console.log);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try change to arrow function

```
  someFunction2=(something:Observable<string>):Observable<string> =>{
    console.log('someFunction1');
    console.log('constant1 = ', this.constant1); 
    // Cannot read property of constant1
    return of('done');
  }
```